# How to programmatically register an Extended Validation OID on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi, x509, pki

I need a way of registering an extended validation OID programmatically - Win32 API, Powershell script, etc, it's not hugely important. It just needs to be automated. But I can't find any way of doing this except manually through certmgr.msc:
[image: Certmgr]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CertSetCertificateContextProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certsetcertificatecontextproperty) CryptoAPI function for this and use `CERT_ROOT_PROGRAM_CERT_POLICIES_PROP_ID` in `dwPropId` parameter.

Comment: Fabulous, although I had some teething issues with getting this to work. Dumb bugs aside, my initial approach using CertFindCertificateInStore() was scuppered by it being a read only context. However, for the application, CertCreateCertificateContext() was appropriate.